# How to call db.getCollectionNames() in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to publish all collections to the client as an array, then show them as a list on a page.

How to call db.getCollectionNames() in meteor?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To use collections in Meteor you need to define them anyways with `YourCollection = new Mongo.Collection('yourCollection')` (http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection) client and server side if you want to use it on both sides. So why not simply push their names to an array at that point if you just want easy access to an array of all Meteor collection names?

Comment: I want to make a simple app to manage my database, so I need to show all collection-names on a page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest your read [this conversation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/532) providing a few answers.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks,I will use Npm.depends. 

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/532#issuecomment-37599403