# Iterate over all collections in Meteor app

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I want to iterate over all the collections created in a Meteor app. The ultimate goal is to write a meteor package that can analyze all collection data for inconsistencies among individual documents.

Using the native mongo [db.getCollectionNames()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912085/how-to-call-db-getcollectionnames-in-meteor) would work in theory but that seems like a janky solution and was hoping there might be a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try anywhere in your server code:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  _.each(global, function(value, key) {
    if (value instanceof Mongo.Collection) {
      console.log("variable name: " + key);
      console.log("collection name: " + value._name);
    }
  });
});
```

It just iterates over the global namespace and looks for instances of `Mongo.Collection`.

Comment: this works with two exceptions I was able to find. 1. if you want the users collection as well you need to do an _.each on the Meteor object and 2. if you use coffee-script its common to put the collections in the share / __coffeescriptShare object so might have to iterate over that as well